# Firemonkey TMemo text auto carriage return

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, word-wrap, tmemo

Is it possible for `TMemo` to automatically show a line from a db adjusted to the width of the `TMemo`? I mean, inside my db i have: "123456789123456789123", and the width of my tmemo is just 10 characters for example.

Is it possible for `TMemo` to automatically show the text in this way?

```
123456789
123456789
123
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved using the [`WordWrap`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Memo.TMemo.WordWrap) property:

```
Memo1.WordWrap := True;
```

This change must be made in code because the memo's `WordWrap` property is not published.

Comment: This is already the default behavior, without changing any properties. The `WordWrap` property is already enabled.

Comment: @JerryDodge This is an FMX question

Comment: As David Heffernan says, this is a FMX question and by default in Delphi XE 7, the WordWrap property is disabled.